# escaping quotes in environment variable within a shell

Tags: shell, environment-variables, double-quotes

I'm trying to use quotes while defining an environment variable.

For example:

```
setenv SOME_TEMP_ENV "-arg "hello world""
```

Although Its fails with the following error:

```
setenv: Too many arguments.
```

After reading some therds about escaping quotes, I tried the following:

```
setenv SOME_TEMP_ENV "-arg \"hello world\""
setenv SOME_TEMP_ENV "-arg '"'"'hello world'"'"'"
```

Also, I could use the following method:

```
setenv SOME_TEMP_ENV "-arg "'"hello world"'""
```

But it doesn't fulfill my requirements:

```
echo $SOME_TEMP_ENV
-arg 'hello world' // should be -arg "hello world"
```

How can I use quotes in an environment variable?

** EDIT **: I have to use the double quotes around the string because my script for some reason can't read the string is its looks like this: `'-arg "hello world"'`

Comment: I have used the `'"'` and `"'"` constructs in more complex quoting situations in `bash`.  Ugly, but sometimes I just want something that works :) .

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes around the string.

```
setenv SOME_TEMP_ENV '-arg "hello world"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using single quotes as the outside wrapper will work in both csh (which your question appears to be about) and bash (which your question was tagged as):

```
'-arg "hello world"'
```